# How to initialize a dynamic array of pointers to NULL in C?

Tags: c

I am fairly new to C and I don't understand why the following two statements do not create the same result:

```
char *fields[14] = {NULL};

const int num_fields = 14;
char *fields[num_fields] = {NULL};
```

Option 1 works, but option 2 does not. It says "variable-sized object may not be initialized" and it gives a warning "warning: excess elements in array initializer".  I use gcc 4.2.1 on OSX.

Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: I think this is probably because a `const int` isn't necessarily a constant value, crazy as that may seem. I believe you can obtain a pointer to the const and modify the underlying value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second object is called a VLA (Variable Length Array), well defined by C99. To achieve what you want you can use this:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
    fields[i] = NULL;
```

The gist of the issue is that `const int num_fields` is very different from `14`, it's not a constant, it's read-only.

Comment: +1 but technically it's not initialization, but assignment. I guess it would be correct to say that VLAs cannot be initialized per se.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I changed the wording.

Comment: Thank you cnicutar for your explanation!

Comment: In a VLA (Variable Length Array) the compiler automatically handles the storage management. Since the size won´t be known until runtime, you can´t use the initializer.

As everybody said. You need a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you define num_fields with const keyword, compiler interprets it as variable only. you can have alternative for this by defining following macro:

#define num_fields         14

char *fields[num_fields] = {NULL};

Answer (score 1):

Although `num_fields` has a `const` qualifier, it is still considered a variable by the compiler.

Therefore, you are attempting to declare a variable-sized array, and initialisers (the `{NULL}` part) cannot be used in conjunction with them.

Comment: Thank you Blagovest Buyukliev for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Your construction works in C++, where a const int will be treated as a compile-time constant ("constant expression"), and hence available for use as a compile-time array size.

(This aspect was one of B. Stroustrup's design goals for C++, to eliminate the need for compile-time macros if possible)

However in C, your definition of "num_fields" effectively declares a read-only memory location with your preset value, and hence is not under C rules a "constant expression" valid at compile time, and hence may not be used as an array size at the outermost 'program' scope.