# How to check for NULL in C of an array of integer pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, null, heap-memory

I have a fixed size array of integer pointers where I want to allocate from heap only if it is needed, but I can't seem to be able to get the following NULL check to work. malloc never get called first.

```
int* seqList[n];
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    int type, x, y;
    scanf("%d", &type);
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    if (type == 1) {
        if (seqList[x] != NULL) {
            int size = sizeof(seqList[x])/sizeof(int*);
            seqList[x] = realloc(seqList[x], (size + 1)*sizeof(int*));
            seqList[x][size] = y;
        }
        else {
            seqList[x] = malloc(sizeof(int*));
        }
    }
    else{
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: because `seqList` isn't initialized. Also `size` is always 1.

Comment: `sizeof(seqList[x])` makes no sense. It will always evaluate to pointer size, meaning that your `size` will always be 1. You will have to store and maintain the current size yourself. `sizeof` will not help you here.

Comment: Also, you don't need to split your code into `malloc` and `realloc` branches. If `seqList[]` is properly initialized to nulls initially, then `realloc` will work properly on it. `realloc` can be used to "reallocate" a null pointer, in which case it is equivalent to `malloc`.

Comment: seqList isn't initialized? Isn't all arrays are initialized automatically? So I assume that I would get an array of null pointers, no?

Comment: @Que Trac: No. Only objects with static storage duration are initialized automatically. Your array is not.

Comment: @Que Trac: If you want initial nulls in `seqList`, just do `int* seqList[n] = { 0 };`. But this will compile only if `n` is a constant.

Comment: just to add to what @AnT said, it must be a compile time constant, not a `const` qualified variable.

Comment: 1. you should not assign the return value of `realloc` to the pointer that was passed as argument, directly. If the new allocation fails you get `NULL` and the old memory is lost.

2. You define `seqList` as array of "pointers to int". But then you allocate `sizeof(int*)` which makes it to array of pointers to pointer to int. You should alloc with `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, BLUEPIXY and AnT. It seems that there isn't any other solution, but to initialize the array as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081136/how-to-initialize-a-dynamic-array-of-pointers-to-null-in-c)

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    seqList[i] = NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize it to 'NULL' to NULL check the array of pointers .

```
  int* seqList[n] = {NULL};
```

or

```
for ( i =0 ; i < n ; i++)
seqList[i] = NULL;
```